# Javascript - Interval not clearing

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game that has a timer in it.

What I'm trying to do is -- when the game starts via `gameState.init()`, the timer starts through `timer.counter("start")` -- but when the "restart" button is clicked, the timer stops and resets through `timer.counter("reset")`.

The timer does reset back to 0, but it keeps counting and not getting cleared.

Appreciate any insight I can get. Thanks in advance!

```
var gameState = {
    init: function(){
        var difficultyLevel = document.querySelector('input[name="level"]:checked').value;
        conditions.difficulty(difficultyLevel);
        startFrame.classList.remove("active");
        shuffleCards();
        timer.counter("start");
        display.moves(movesAllowed);
    },
    restart: function(){
        startFrame.classList.add("active");
        reset.allCards(cards);
        shuffleCards();
        timer.counter("reset");
        matchCount = 0;
        totalMoves = 0;
        movesAllowed = 0;
        timeAllowed = 0;
        time = 0;
    }
}

var timer = {
    counter: function(status){
        var clock = document.querySelector(".timer");

        var incrementTime = setInterval(function(){
                time++;
                var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
                var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
                if(seconds < 10){
                    clock.innerText = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
                } else {
                    clock.innerText = minutes + ":" + seconds;
                }
            }, 1000);

        var stopTime = function(){
            clearInterval(incrementTime);
        }

        if(status === "start"){
            alert("counting");
        }

        if(status === "reset"){;
            alert("reset");
            stopTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a different interval each time you call timer.counter(status) so of course it is not going to stop the previous interval you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- The variable that holds the interval, `incrementTime`, is local to the `counter` function. Once the `counter` function ends, `incrementTime` gets garbage collected, because no reference to the interval remains anymore. You need the interval variable to be *persistent* instead.
- You're setting a new interval *every time* `counter` is called. You should probably only set an interval when `status` is `start`, otherwise the old interval will continue running and won't be stoppable (reassigning the interval a `setInterval` is assigned to doesn't clear the interval):

  ```
  let interval; // <---- Persistent
  var timer = {
    counter: function(status){
      var clock = document.querySelector(".timer");
      if (status === 'start') {
        interval = setInterval(() => { // <---- Assign to persistent variable
          time++;
          var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
          var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
          if(seconds < 10){
            clock.innerText = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
          } else {
            clock.innerText = minutes + ":" + seconds;
          }
        }, 1000);
        alert("counting");
      } else if(status === "reset"){
        var stopTime = function(){
          clearInterval(interval); // <---- Clear persistent variable
        }
        alert("reset");
        stopTime();
      }
    }
  }
  ```

(It would also be a bit more elegant for the `stopTime` and interval functions to be persistent, rather than being re-created every time they're needed; eg, you might assign them to properties of `timer`)